# Unirest shutdown to exit program

Tags: java, unirest

I try to update resources with scheduled tasks using `Unirest.get(...).asObjectAsync(...)`. To stop a program employing Unirest, you need to call `Unirest.shutdown();` to exit its event loops and clients. However, if some threads call Unirest's request methods after a successful shutdown, the program can not exit.

The following code is a very simple example: I start a thread which does a GET request after 1.5 seconds and prints the status message when it was successful. Meanwhile on the main thread, Unirest is shut down. (Note that example this uses `asStringAsync(...)` and a very simple thread for simplicity.)

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.async.Callback;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Unirest.get("http://example.org").asStringAsync(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(HttpResponse<String> response) {
                    System.out.println(response.getStatusText());
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                    System.out.println("failed");
                }

                @Override
                public void cancelled() {
                    System.out.println("cancelled");
                }
            });
        }).start();
        Unirest.shutdown();
    }
}
```

What I expected was any of these cases:

- The program shuts down and no output is there.
- The program shuts down and I get any of these outputs: the status message, failed or cancelled.
- The program shuts down but throws an exception because Unirest is already shut when the GET request occurs.

What I got:

- The program does not shut down and the GET request succeeds, printing "OK".

How can I handle a graceful exit with Unirest? Should I restructure the program (and if so, how)?

I am using Java 8 on Windows, running the code inside IntelliJ Idea 14.1.5.
The unirest dependency I use is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
    <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you have spawned a thread which runs the async call. The `shutdown()` call is in your main thread, so by the time that the call thread spawns, `shutdown()` will have been called *before* the `asStringAsync()` method of Unirest can be first called.

It is the first call to an `..Async()` that instantiates the thread pool that will eventually need to be shut down - there is nothing to shut down at the time which you call the shutdown method, and so it is a no-op. It will be instantiated in the thread you created.

The solution here is to remove the thread that you have created, and make use the `Future` object that Unirest gives you. Unirest handles the thread itself when you do the async call, and you can input the callback logic as necessary.

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Future<HttpResponse<String>> asyncCall = Unirest.get("http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml&results_per_page=20").asStringAsync(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void completed(HttpResponse<String> response) {
            System.out.println(response.getStatusText());
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(UnirestException e) {
            System.out.println("failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {
            System.out.println("cancelled");
        }
    });
    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = asyncCall.get(); // Can also use Future.isDone(), etc
    // System.out.println(httpResponse.getBody());
    Unirest.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

asyncCall.get() will block the call, so it is better to do as below:

```
asyncCall.thenAcceptAsync((result)->{   
if (null != result && !result.isEmpty()) {
        // do your business logic after response and then close Unirest
        Unirest.shutdown();
         }
    });
   }
```

But in the case of cleaning resources, you can always re-use same created one and register a shutdown hook that will clean everything during JVM shutdown.

Reference: http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#configuration